# Why is the CPU not maxed out?

Tags: sql-server, io, cpu, performance

I have an application that I'd like to make more efficient - it isn't taxing any one resource enough that I can identify it as a bottleneck, so perhaps the app is doing something that is preventing full efficiency.

The application pulls data from a database on one SQL Server instance, does some manipulation on it, then writes it to a database on another SQL Server instance - all on one machine. It doesn't do anything in parallel.

While the app is running (it can take several hours), none of the 4 CPU cores are maxed out (they hover around 40-60% utilization each), the disks are almost idle and very little RAM is used.

Reported values:

```
Target SQL Server instance: ~10% CPU utilization, 1.3GB RAM
Source SQL Server instance: ~10% CPU utilization, 300MB RAM
Application: ~6% CPU utilization, 45MB RAM
```

All the work is happening on one disk, which writes around 100KB/s during the operation, on average. 'Active time' according to task manager is usually 0%, occasionally flickering up to between 1 and 5% for a second or so. Average response time, again according to task manager, moves betweeen 0ms and 20ms, mainly showing between 0.5 and 2ms.

Comment: I don't understand very well how it works. Poor operation can may be due to some bad configuration of hardware, operating system or server. What OS you use? However, take a look on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647793.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Databases are notorious for IO limitations. Now, seriously, as you say:

> The application pulls data from a database on one SQL Server instance,
>   does some manipulation on it, then writes it to a database on another
>   SQL Server instance - all on one machine.

I somehow get the idea this is a end user level mashine, maybe a workstation. Your linear code (a bad idea to get full utilization btw, as you never run all 3 parts - read, process, write - in parallel) will be seriously limited by whatever IO subsystem you have.

But that will not come into play as long as you can state:

> It doesn't do anything in parallel.

What it must do is do things in parallel:

- One task is reading the next data
- One task does the data processing
- One task does the data writing

You can definitely max out a lot more than your 4 cores. Last time I did something like that (read / manipulate / write) we were maxing out 48 cores with around 96 or so processing threads running in parallel (and a smaller amount doing the writes). But a core of that is that your application msut start actually using multiple CPU's.

If you do not parallelize:

- You only will max out one core max,
- YOu basically waste time waiting for databases on both ends. The latency while you wait for data to be read or committed is latency you are not processing anything.

;) And once you fix that you will get IO problems. Promised.

Comment: Thanks. The processing actually operates one 'record' at a time on several thousand, so the easiest (in terms of application design) way to make this do some work in parallel could be to have a certain number of records be operated upon in parallel. There's no ordering dependency for these records, so this should be safe.

Comment: This is 100% like we did it. One thread making a select statement, pushing every record into a processing queue, X threads doing the processing, feeding the output into writer queues, Y writer queues doing the writes ;) We processe like 400 million records in around 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/). You need to capture and analyze the wait stats. These will tell you what is the execution doing that prevents it from going max out on CPU. You already have a feeling that the workload is causing the SQL engine to *wait* rather than *run*, but only after you understand the wait stats you'll be able to get a feel what is waiting *for*. Follow the article linked for specific analysis techniques.